# Windows Phone AdRotator, location aware

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, ads, adrotator, location-aware

I'm planing to use [adrotator](http://wp7adrotator.codeplex.com/) with location aware apps.

My app to pass on certification needs to have an option to disable the use of location (and a location policy), but I can't find any way to turn off the location on the adrotator, I searched everywhere for an answer and nothing.

Does anyone knows how to solve this? (beside from using two adrotators, one for location aware and other to non location aware)